# Should course-specific sites appear in the site switcher?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-exchange-button, communities-list

Site switcher currently shows two sites (private betas) that are intended for students in specific [edX](https://www.edx.org/) courses, namely [HarvardX CS50](https://cs50.stackexchange.com/) and [BerkeleyX CS169](https://edx-cs169-1x.stackexchange.com/).

[image]

I think this is a bug, because the sites are not shown in the [full list](https://stackexchange.com/sites). It would make sense to show them in both places, or in neither. (The latter makes more sense to me than the former.)

Comment: Huh?!? Where did these come from?

Comment: I don't think private beta's you don't have access to should show up in the site switcher (but those you do should), but the full list doesn't show private beta sites, which makes sense.

Comment: @AsheeshR [What is cs50 and why can't I access it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/228721) - unfortunately no useful information from the team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Private betas are no longer locked down like they once used to be (they're accessible at any time from Area 51), so removing them entirely isn't necessary. In fact, they're deliberately included in the site switcher to increase their discoverability. The site switcher is newer than the full site list on stackexchange.com, so if anything, we should reconsider hiding them there.

These two course-specific sites are [experimental](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/228721). At the moment we don't have a site state for "fully private" and special-casing individual sites in our code is just going to turn into an unmaintainable mess very quickly, so we aren't planning to make any decisions about how sites like those are handled until we know how successful those experiments turn out to be.