# Is there a reason that CS50 and edx-cs169-1x are not present in SEDE?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

I left a comment on [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251524/whats-the-most-isolated-se-site) suggesting to try a cross-database query to get a reliable statistic (I did mention that it might run for too long but that is not the point).

After seeing [nicael's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251525/158100) I realized I didn't recall seeing cs50 or edx-cs169-1x among the [SEDE dabases](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/289912). And that makes my comment misleading.

Those [sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231208/what-is-story-behind-the-edx-stackexchanges) seem to be [different](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/229996/158100) with respect to the process they followed and have slightly different/added functionality. They are, however, still part of the SE network.

What is the reason those sites are not available in SEDE?

If this is a simple oversight, can those be added so I could in theory answer [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251524/whats-the-most-isolated-se-site) with one of my nifty sql scripts?

Comment: As Anna says [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/229306/152859): "These two course-specific sites are experimental" - so no reason to add them to SEDE, most likely.

Comment: Ok, but I can sign-up so they are not private in that respect, right?

Comment: they're not private, but also not  full part of Stack Exchange yet. Kind of "zombie" - neither dead nor alive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Techincally, those sites are in private beta. And there is currently no reason for SE staff to consider it promoting to public beta - it is quite for limited amount of users.

Therefore those sites behave just like any private betas.

For example:

- privileges at private beta level
- **unavailability in SE data explorer**, just like with any site in private beta
- absence from the [lists of sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites)
- questions can't become hot and appear in the hot questions lists
- and so on....

And just by the way, you commented:

> but I can sign-up so they are not private in that respect

Actually you can sign in any private beta site by going to its proposal page on Area 51 and clicking "Visit the site now!".

Comment: OK, that could be true. But in that case the question raises if you can consider then SE communities as intended by the asker of that other question?

Comment: @rene they are still communities, why aren't  they? Or I misunderstood your comment?

Comment: No, you're right. I'm just confused when we sometimes consider those communities all equal and in a different context they become private. That is all.

Comment: @rene In case of *those* communities, you probably realize that they just have their own audience, that's like their corner :) They appear to be exceptions and, to be honest, I am not sure why Stack Exchange decided to start new communities solely for the students of specific universities.

Comment: nicael is correct. The edX sites were left with the private beta settings to avoid all the "side effects" listed above. The administrators have conveyed that they wish to continuing using the sites we have, but for all intents and purposes, they are not really part of the Stack Exchange Network of sites.

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifying that