# CS50.SE isn't shown in the list of communities in the dropdown menu

Tags: support, ios-app

In my Stack Exchange iOS app, when I list the Sites, there is a site called CS50 there:

> [image]

But when I look in "More Stack Exchange Communities" in the dropdown on the website, I can not find it; how can I navigate to the CS50 site via the dropdown menu?

> [image]

I also tried in the [Stack Exchange sites list](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#technology-name), but it isn't there either.

Is this scenario is normal?

Because I always switch sites in Stack Exchange from there, if the list has no CS50, I don't know how to switch to it. typing the domain is too hard to remember.

Comment: @Glorfindel See my EDIT, friend. If there is no that, I don't know how to switch to it now, and I don't know whether do not exist the `CS50` is normal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CS50 isn't a normal Stack Exchange site. It was [part of an experimental partnership with edX](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231208/307988), which has mostly been stopped. CS50 is still active enough to be kept alive for now though.

The sites are kept separate and hidden from the rest of the network as they aren't of much use to regular users. The fact that it shows up in the apps I assume is simply because they aren't hidden from the Stack Exchange API (which you can see [here](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites#pagesize=400&filter=!SlEYrR1.qj(3bM31Le&run=true))).

Comment: It's in the status of private beta behind the scenes, probably the app simply doesn't filter those out like the web does. :)

Comment: If I remember correctly, we let users view private betas in the app but not sign up.  A smarter design would have been to hide private betas from the site list *unless* the account has a user on the site.