# Which Stack Exchange sites have dedicated sponsors?

Tags: support, sponsored-sites

Some Stack Exchange sites have a 'sponsored by' logo just under the top bar:

[image: A screenshot of the Software Engineering Stack Exchange header bar, with the text "Sponsored by Stack Overflow for Teams" at the right side]

Which sites in the network are/were [sponsored](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307861/295232), by which company/organization/product and when did that start?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

#### Current / upcoming sponsorships

These sites in the network are sponsored through the formal site sponsorship program (ordered by start date, end date, then site name):

| Site | Company | Start date | End date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [Salesforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/) | Gearset | [July 1, 2021](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3096) | March 31, 2024 |
| [Quantum Computing](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/) | AWS | [January 16, 2023](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/572) | January 16, 2024 |
| [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/) | Hashicorp | [May 25, 2023](https://devops.meta.stackexchange.com/q/393) | December 29, 2023 |
| [GenAI](https://genai.stackexchange.com/) | Stack Overflow Labs | [July 25, 2023](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/80) | unspecified |
| [Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) | WB Discovery | [November 29, 2023](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2979) | May 29, 2024 |

Additionally, three sites are sponsored informally, under special agreements that were negotiated before SE launched the formal site sponsorship program:

| Site | Company | Start date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) | Canonical ([more information](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/19689/606366)) | [October 11, 2010](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/10/11/ubuntu-stack-exchange-is-askubuntu-com/) |
| [Ask Patents](https://askpatents.com/) | U.S. Patents & Trademarks Office | [September 20, 2012](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/09/20/askpatents-com-a-stack-exchange-to-prevent-bad-patents/) |
| [CS50](https://cs50.stackexchange.com/) | edX | [somewhere before May 2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231238/377214) |

Comment: Should DevOps be moved into the other answer now?

Answer (score 4):

#### Past sponsorships

The following sites have been sponsored in the past:

| Site | Company | Start date | End date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) | Intel | [November 11, 2021](https://datascience.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2584) | February 7, 2022 |
| [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com) | Octopus Deploy | [October 30, 2020](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/9680/283889) | [September 10, 2021](https://web.archive.org/web/20210910011416/https://serverfault.com/) |
| [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) | IBM | [February 4, 2021](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5735/111051) | [May 3, 2021](http://web.archive.org/web/20210503000517/https://unix.stackexchange.com/) |
| [Artificial Intelligence](https://ai.stackexchange.com/) | IBM | [September 5, 2018](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1404/4709) | [January 1, 2020](https://web.archive.org/web/20200101070209/https://ai.stackexchange.com/) |
| [Artificial Intelligence](https://ai.stackexchange.com/) | AWS machine learning | [January 14, 2020](https://web.archive.org/web/20200114103020/https://ai.stackexchange.com/) | [March 26, 2020](http://web.archive.org/web/20200327171226/https://ai.stackexchange.com/) |
| [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) | AWS machine learning | [January 3, 2020](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5833/79696) | [March 26, 2020](http://web.archive.org/web/20200327010749/https://stats.stackexchange.com/) |
| [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/) | New Relic | [July 31, 2020](https://devops.meta.stackexchange.com/q/346/1180) | [December 17, 2020](http://web.archive.org/web/20201217145933/https://devops.stackexchange.com/) |
| [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) | Stack Overflow for Teams | [July 18, 2019](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8979/173647) | [January 16, 2020](https://web.archive.org/web/20200116081512/https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) |
| [Quantum Computing](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/) | Strangeworks | [March 12, 2018](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1/45) | [May 21, 2021](https://web.archive.org/web/20210522013159/https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/) |
| [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) | AWS | [September 27, 2021](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3447) | December 31, 2022 |
| [Super User](https://superuser.com/) | AWS | [September 27, 2021](https://meta.superuser.com/q/14539) | December 31, 2022 |
| [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) | AWS | [September 27, 2021](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5846) | December 31, 2022 |
| [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/) | Auth0 | [April 21, 2022](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3478) | December 31, 2022 |
| [Artificial Intelligence](https://ai.stackexchange.com/) | AWS | [July 18, 2022](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2895) | December 31, 2022 |
| [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) | AWS | [July 18, 2022](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6347) | December 31, 2022 |
| [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) | AWS | [July 18, 2022](https://datascience.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2628) | December 31, 2022 |
| [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) | AWS | [July 18, 2022](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/9819) | December 31, 2022 |
| [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) | AWS | [July 22, 2022](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4109) | December 31, 2022 |
| [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) | AWS | [July 22, 2022](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/20063) | December 31, 2022 |
| [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) | AWS | [July 22, 2022](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4865) | December 31, 2022 |
| [Drupal Answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/) | Pantheon | [May 26, 2023](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3912) | November 15, 2023 |
| [Startups](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6243/startup-business) | OnStartups | [December 7, 2009](https://smallbiztrends.com/2009/12/question-site-entrepreneurs-answers-onstartups.html) | ? |

In addition, there was sponsorship on other edX course forum sites (now closed), by edX, until [about April 2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231238/377214).