# Are the 'Quantum Computing' and 'Artificial Intelligence' sites still in Beta?

Tags: support, design, beta-sites, sidebar, site-stats

On [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/), the proposal pages for [Quantum Computing](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/106955/quantum-computing) and [Artificial Intelligence](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93481/artificial-intelligence) both say, "This site is in Public Beta".

However, the Home pages of [Quantum Computing](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/) and [Artificial Intelligence](https://ai.stackexchange.com/) don't have the Site Stats sidebar that all Beta sites have. They also have distinctive topbars and colour schemes, and the site names in the topbar don't have the "Beta" logo next to them.

At first, I thought this was because these are/were sponsored sites, according to [Which Stack Exchange sites have dedicated sponsors?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/341662#341663). However, the [Ask Patents](https://patents.stackexchange.com/) and [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/) sites are/were also sponsored sites, and the former has a Site Stats sidebar along with having a distinctive topbar and theme and missing the Beta label in the site name, and the latter looks exactly like any other Beta site, including the Site Stats sidebar, theme, and Beta label in the site name.

What accounts for the differences between these sites? Have Quantum Computing and Artificial Intelligence graduated and their Area 51 pages not been updated for some reason?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're still in beta; they have the [privilege levels](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) of a beta site ([some non-beta sites have these too](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331708/295232), but they are much older) and the [API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites#pagesize=500&filter=default&run=true) says they're in beta too:

[image]

The difference is that they have a design (because of the sponsorship) which doesn't fit too well with a Beta label on the front page. DevOps doesn't have a design (yet? I'm not aware of any plans) and Ask Patents has its [own specific privilege levels](https://patents.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) (and that sponsorship predates the other ones by several years).

Comment: Thank you for clarifying! I surmised as much about the lack of the Beta label being linked to the sponsorship, but the lack of the Site Stats sidebar confused me specifically.

Comment: How can you see if it's beta via the API?

Comment: @Daniil I've updated the answer with a link to the API call. In the results you see `"site_state": "open_beta"` for the corresponding sites.

Comment: Privilege levels don't indicate that site is in beta

Comment: True, but in combination with the age of the site it does. I'd like to write something like 'all sites with a design but reduced privilege levels are beta sites', but the sites in question (AI and QC) are the only ones, so that'd be a circular reasoning.