# Site Sponsorships - no more?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, sponsored-sites

Five years ago, [Site Sponsorships were launched](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307861/site-sponsorships-bringing-resources-back-to-stack-exchange).

It had its share of problems and bugs, but all in all the sponsored sites did show logo of their sponsor and all was fine.

However, now out of the 12 sites there were sponsored back in 2022 (see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341662/which-stack-exchange-sites-have-dedicated-sponsors)), only one is still officially sponsored, [Salesforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/) however **even on this site there's no sponsor logo**.

The three unofficially sponsored sites also don't show any sign they're sponsored anymore.

This leads to the inevitable question: has the Site Sponsorship been sunset?

Comment: Are you running any extensions, such as an adblocker?

Comment: @Laurel no userscripts, no extensions, no blockers. You see sponsored logo on sites? Can you post screenshot please?

Comment: I can confirm they seem gone.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMabu.png super user - which should be sponsored by AWS and https://i.stack.imgur.com/ha3KT.png salesforce

Comment: It shows up on [Salesforce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEnN3.png). The unofficial ones don't have a header ad but I don't think they ever had one. Browser: iOS Chrome.

Comment: I've now checked, with all adblockers, add-ons, userscripts etc. disabled, on Chrome for Ubuntu 22.04, Firefox for Ubuntu 22.04, Chrome for Windows 10, Firefox for Windows 10, Edge for Windows 10, Chrome for Android 11, and Samsung Browser for Android 11. On none of them did the sponsored logo show up on Salesforce.

Comment: @Laurel on which page? I can't see it anywhere, neither logged in, nor incognito. It sounds like either a bug or a silent sponsorship termination, because [as per official post](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3096/10162) the site was going to be sponsored until September, 2023

Comment: The downvotes on this question are apparently coming from the sponsors who are not seeing their logos...

Comment: @Laurel looks like your OS has very strong cache, try to clear it.

Comment: @nicael or people who think I'm asking to sunset site sponsorship, in such case downvotes make sense. But all good, Mr. Geek kicked this into review and now we just have to wait.

Comment: @nicael On every page, even newly posted questions. I don't see how this can be a problem with my cache, since it shows up in iOS Safari in incognito too, which I rarely use for SE. For whatever reason the banner ad doesn't show up on other devices on my network — not even a different iOS phone.

Comment: @Laurel this gave me a hint and I checked, it appears to be geo-dependent. I'm in Israel and it [doesn't show to me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adZNs.png); but once I fired up a Germany VPN, I was able to [see the logo right away](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etouo.png)

Comment: @nicael +1 data point here. I am in Germany, the logo shows up for me on Salesforce, and I have never visited Salesforce before today.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They have not been sunset.

At this time we have two active site sponsorships (Quantum Computing and Salesforce). As we've been doing, we'll be notifying communities on their meta sites of any upcoming site sponsorships.

Both of the sponsorships show up for me (in incognito mode, no ad blocker):

[image: Salesforce top bar with Gearset sponsor logo.]
[image: Quantum Computing top bar with AWS sponsor logo.]

We did some digging as a result of this post and discovered that one of the sponsorships was incorrectly displaying in only some areas. We're working to resolve this - thanks for bringing it to our attention.

Comment: It does surprise me that so few sites have active sponsorship.