# Can you have a Stack Exchange-like page for each school class?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, area-51

It would be great to be able to have mini-Stack Exchange sites for each course that I'm taking in university.

At the moment we're using Piazaa or some generic forum. But having a Stack-Overflow like page for each class would make Q & A much more effective.

This would require people to be able to create temporal Stack Exchange sites, like:

www.university.stackexchange.com/UniversityOfToronto/CSC458

etc..

Thoughts?

Comment: Interesting idea...

Comment: I'm not sure what the outcome of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228721/what-is-cs50-and-why-cant-i-access-it was.