# Which Stack Exchange sites weren't proposed in Area 51?

Tags: discussion, area-51, stack-exchange, stack-exchange-history

Recently I found some sites that are a part of the Stack Exchange network but were not proposed. In other words, I'm talking about sites that are not established through Area51, like Super User.

Which sites are these that are part of the Stack Exchange network and have not been proposed / were not established through Area51?

Comment: That would be easy enough for you to work out for yourself. Any sites that existed before Stack Exchange 2.0 didn't go through area 51. So look at http://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#oldest and go through them from top to bottom until you find one that was proposed through Area51. All the ones above that weren't. Then, add on any remaining sites with a custom domain (merged into SE network), and you have your list. Writing an answer now.

Comment: Not quite right, @wizzwizz4.

Comment: @Oded I know, the Russian Language site was given a Stack Exchange URL, and the Russian Stack Overflow didn't go through Area 51. Seeing as your answer is definitive and correct, I won't write my incomplete one.

Comment: Considering CS50 is in beta, I'd say it is indeed an a51 proposal

Comment: @Trojan How does that follow? I think even SO had a beta stage at some point, back in the mists of time. I tried searching Area 51, and there aren't any proposals called CS50 there.

Comment: interesting. I guess not, then.

Comment: Some information about CS50: [What is CS50 and why can't I access it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228721/what-is-cs50-and-why-cant-i-access-it) & [What is story behind the edX Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231208/what-is-story-behind-the-edx-stack-exchange-sites)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

#### Trilogy sites

The original three (also called [the trilogy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/40353/260388)) came into being before Area 51 existed:

- Stack Overflow
- Server Fault
- Super User

#### Sites fully migrated from Stack Exchange 1.0

After that, three sites that were created via the former Stack Exchange 1.0 model got fully merged into the network (the idea behind Stack Exchange 1.0 was to host sites on different topics for other people in exchange for payment - this didn't work):

- MathOverflow - sole site to be migrated "as is", with no change in scope or association to an Area 51 proposal. The site is operated by Stack Exchange on behalf of its original owners under a [special agreement](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4429/what-is-mathoverflows-agreement-with-stack-exchange). Additionally, it was allowed to retain many design elements of Stack Exchange 1.0 that were later removed, until all network sites were redesigned in 2018.
- Mi Yodeya - was associated with a later Area 51 proposal for a Judaism site, but wasn't created on Area 51 per se
- Sound Design - this site was previously known as Social Sound Design with a narrower scope. Upon becoming a member of the network, the site known as Audio-Video Production had all its audio questions moved to this site, and its scope was narrowed to just Video Production.

There were some other Stack Exchange 1.0 sites that were created, but they either had their content seeded into later sites created through Area 51, or ceased to be Stack Exchange sites (with some migrating their content over to non-Stack Exchange software).

#### Meta sites about Stack Exchange

- Stack Apps - which, though using the same Q&A engine, is not really a Q&A site; manually created in order to host and promote programs using the Stack Exchange API
- Meta Stack Exchange - came into being as Meta Stack Overflow to supersede an old meta discussion site on the UserVoice platform before Area 51 existed; subsequently renamed and re-scoped, with a new per-site meta created for Stack Overflow
- Area 51 and Area 51 Discussions, for obvious reasons

#### Special projects

- Ask Patents - was created in collaboration with the U.S. Patents and Trademarks Office
- Generative AI (formerly named Prompt Design) - was fleshed out with "stakeholders" on a Teams instance after being announced on meta.SE in 2023: [Starting the Prompt Design Site: A New Home in our Stack Exchange Neighborhood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/390463)

#### hashcode.ru acquisition (fully migrated sites)

In 2015, Stack Exchange purchased hashcode.ru, which was a Russian operator of Stack Exchange-like Q&A sites. Some of their sites were migrated into our network, never going through Area 51:

- ru.stackoverflow.com - for programmers, in Russian (later associated with a previous Area 51 proposal for a Russian-language version of Stack Overflow, but wasn't created through Area 51)
- rus.stackexchange.com - for Russian language, in Russian (not to be confused with russian.stackexchange.com, or Russian Language in English, which was created through Area 51)
- ru.meta.stackoverflow.com - today the per-site meta for Stack Overflow in Russian; however, it was previously known as meta.hashcode.ru and served as the global meta for all sites in the hashcode.ru network (no per-site metas); content from that site was migrated in

#### hashcode.ru acquisition (non-migrated, separately operated sites)

In addition to the above sites which were migrated into our network, Stack Exchange runs the following sites previously operated by hashcode.ru (also known as sezn.ru), which weren't created through Area 51. These sites are [entirely separate from the rest of the Stack Exchange network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316022/whats-to-become-of-the-remaining-hashcode-ru-sites) and operated on their own server, which nevertheless is legally owned by Stack Exchange:

- math.hashcode.ru - for mathematics help, in Russian; was large enough to be considered for migrating into our network, but community members there objected to importing the site since the rules regarding homework questions would have to be changed
- phys.sezn.ru - for physics enthusiasts, in Russian; was supposed to be shut down as part of a mass shutdown of hashcode.ru communities that were deemed too small for migration, but kept up due to oversight from the team; was decided to retain in current form due to a small number of active users
- turism.sezn.ru - for travel questions, in Russian; see above entry

#### edX partnership

There is the following site, which was created in collaboration with edX, but is not technically part of the network:

- cs50.stackexchange.com - for those completing the CS50x edX course

This category was created as a special partnership with edX, to have their forum system migrated to our engine. There were plans to create more such sites for all their courses, and a few more were created, but things just didn't work out and the partnership was dissolved and all these sites except the one above were shut down.

#### Honorable mentions

- ja.stackoverflow.com - this site was proposed and created through Area 51, but the proposal no longer exists. It was removed as part of a mass deletion of all non-English proposals in 2015 due to a lack of resources, but shortly afterwards, space opened up for one more site. The site was then launched, but the Area 51 proposal remains deleted.

I believe these are all of them.

Comment: Why is this slightly more enjoyable than a history class?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are several other special cases that you missed, like [sound.SE] which [also used to be an SE 1.0 site.](https://sound.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/time-for-a-big-upgrade-to-ssd)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen You're right. Two more SE 1.0 imports: [SharePoint](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1) and [Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5), both links point to meta threads about the migration to SE 2.0.

Answer (score 23):

#### Sites without an Area 51 page

- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) (predates Area 51)
- [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) (predates Area 51)
- [Super User](https://superuser.com/) (predates Area 51)
- [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/) (SE 1.0 site, imported but still somewhat special within SE 2.0)
- [Sound Design](https://sound.stackexchange.com/) (SE 1.0 site, the last to be imported)
- [スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/) (special project,  internationalization)
- [Ask Patents](https://patents.stackexchange.com/) (special project with USPTO)
- [Русский язык](https://rus.stackexchange.com/) (imported along with Stack Overflow in Russian)
- [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) (not really a Q&A site)
- [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/) (not really a Q&A site)
- [CS50](https://cs50.stackexchange.com/) (not really a Stack Exchange site)

#### Edge cases

Some sites have an Area 51 page, but nonetheless weren't really created through Area 51, as they predate their appearance on Area 51. These sites were either newly created and seeded with content from a prior SE 1.0 site; others were created outside and subsequently re-associated with existing Area 51 proposals:

- [Electrical Engineering](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2651/electrical-engineering) (seeded with content from former SE 1.0 site Chiphacker)
- [Homebrewing](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com) (seeded with content from former SE 1.0 site Brew Advice)
- [Mi Yodeya](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/22435/mi-yodeya) (SE 1.0 site; re-associated with "Judaism" proposal on Area 51)
- [Personal Finance & Money](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1721/personal-finance-and-money) (seeded with content from former SE 1.0 site Basically Money)
- [SharePoint](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/28921/sharepoint) (seeded with content from former SE 1.0 site SharePoint Overflow)
- [Stack Overflow in Russian](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41168/stack-overflow-in-russian) (formerly hashcode.ru; the Area 51 proposal existed independently of the import, and was later connected to the already-launched site)
- [User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com) (seeded with content from former SE 1.0 site UXExchange)

Comment: "*Meta Stack Exchange (not really a Q&A site)*" - hey, what d'you mean? I just posted a question here and got an answer! :-P

Comment: @Randal'Thor MSE is a feedback site rather that Q&A site!