# Which sites have graduated?

Tags: support, graduating-sites

When a beta site is shown to have a strong, healthy community, it can be selected for site graduation.

Most graduated sites can be identified by their unique design and site logo. However, [this is not always the case](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263905/351462).

- Which sites have been chosen for graduation?
- Which sites have graduated without a unique design?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a [list of graduated sites](https://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=launched) on Area 51. Sites which don't have a unique design (yet) are easily recognized by their blue text balloon icons (the same as they had while still in beta).

[image]

At the moment of posting, the following sites are still waiting on their design after graduating:

- [Anime & Manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/)
- [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)
- [Philosophy](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/)
- [Law](https://law.stackexchange.com/)
- [Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/)
- [Quantitative Finance](https://quant.stackexchange.com/)
- [Ethereum](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/)
- [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/)
- [Arduino](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: That list is incomplete because not all sites went through Area 51. For example, [Ask Patents](https://patents.stackexchange.com/) and [Japanese SO](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/) aren't in Area 51 at all.

Comment: @Laurel it seems [Ask Patents never graduated](https://patents.meta.stackexchange.com/a/220/17737). I'm not sure about ja.SO but I can't check because of insufficient skills in Japanese.

Comment: ja.SO has not graduated; they had another pro tem added [just this month](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2533), no [elections](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/election) and beta-level [privileges](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges). But the list of [sites without Area 51 page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/289806) contains four graduated ones: [so], [su], [sf], and [mathoverflow.se] (cc: @Laurel)