# Where are users of the two Russian-language sites which weren't migrated to Stack Exchange 2.0 supposed to ask meta questions?

Tags: support, russian-stackoverflow

As of now, there are two Q&A sites in the Russian language, http://math.hashcode.ru/ and http://phys.sezn.ru/, which are owned and maintained by Stack Exchange as a result of its acquisition of the former owners of those sites, but are entirely separate from the Stack Exchange network of sites as the [decision was made not to migrate them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316022/whats-to-become-of-the-remaining-hashcode-ru-sites).

Back when these sites were under their prior ownership, there used to be a site http://meta.hashcode.ru/, which served as the global meta site for all sites within their network. Today, that redirects to https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/, which serves as a per-site meta for Stack Overflow in Russian.

Are meta questions about these two sites on-topic on that site, since the "meta" link on those sites goes to the above site? Or are only questions about Stack Overflow in Russian on-topic there?

If the latter, where are users of those two sites supposed to ask meta questions? Can the "meta" link on those sites please be updated to that location?

Comment: seems like meta ruSO is a only place for meta question for this sites

Comment: "which are owned and maintained by Stack Exchange" - not sure about this.

Comment: It is not accurate to say they are owned and maintained by Stack Exchange. As pointed out in the answer, only Nic has access there, and none of the rest of the company does *anything* whatsoever to support those two remaining sites.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> which are owned and maintained by Stack Exchange as a result of its
>   acquisition of the former owners of those sites

Not sure about it, actually. Discussions about this sites appear from time to time on our meta. And, as far as I can see, only Nicolas has admin access to this sites.

Right now I've found only few of them:

1. [Какие сайты Сети Знаний существуют?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5778/15479)
2. [Что случилось с сайтом "∞ Математика"?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7700/15479)

Some answers/comments could be seen only by high rep users ('cause where deleted). The points here are:

1. Only Nicolas has access to this sites (and looks like he is the only one who cares about them. Or he just pretends (¬‿¬ )).
2. Looking on past promises by him (for example, about redirection instead of 500 for http://careers.hashcode.ru/; and many others), looks like he doesn't care about this sites anymore, or he has no time for them.

> Are meta questions about these two sites on-topic on that site, since
>   the "meta" link on those sites goes to the above site?

SOru is more loyal, so usually we don't close/delete such questions on our meta.

> Or are only questions about Stack Overflow in Russian on-topic there?

By "there" you mean MSE or https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com?

> If the latter, where are users of those two sites supposed to ask meta
>   questions?

They do it on our meta. But it's not that often, so there is not actually problem.

> Can the "meta" link on those sites please be updated to that location?

We have asked Nicolas about this several times, but without results, as you can see =/

Comment: *usually we don't close/delete such questions on our meta* ... not me! 