# Hashcode sites are unmoderated and spam-filled

Tags: feature-request, moderation, spam

Hashcode is a network of Russian Q&A sites that was bought by Stack Overflow in 2015. The most active sites for programming and Russian were imported to Stack Exchange, but not all were. A few sites are still on the old, unmaintained Hashcode software. The [site for physics](http://phys.sezn.ru/) is still around, and appears to be completely unmoderated. All of the last ~200 questions are spam for essay-writing services. The spam is written in English, instead of Russian:

[image: "Buy Essay Online For Cheap 24", "College Essay Buying", "Custom Essay Writing Service Online"]

It seems that there is nobody around to moderate this site. Someone at Stack Exchange should clean up this spam. But given that nobody else has noticed this, it might be time to shut down this site: it doesn't appear anyone cares about this site.

The [tourism site](http://turism.sezn.ru/questions/) also has a handful of spam questions, and **has not had a non-spam post for 7 years**. It doesn't seem to be worth keeping around.

Comment: Related: [What's to become of the remaining hashcode.ru sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316022/323179). In any case, the math site looks fine, while the careers site keeps spam away with its server error page. But at least we know what ancient version of Apache they use now.

Comment:  I didn't know half these sites existed at all until a few minutes ago, and what their status is. I'll ask around, since I'm not even sure of whether hashcode is on topic here, or what their method of governance is

Comment: Side question: I didn't know those sites existed either. But... if Stack Exchange is going to keep those sites around, can/will SE (properly) setup HTTPS on those sites? Currently, the HTTPS certs for those sites are from a totally different domain (why?) and if SE plans to keep them, adding valid SSL certs would be nice.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Also, while we're on the topic of security... [The page that Laurel mentioned errors](http://careers.hashcode.ru/) and displays that it's running Apache 2.2.22... which is [over a decade old](https://www.serverwatch.com/server-news/apache-http-server-2-2-22-released/). And [is EOL with many known vunerabilites](https://httpd.apache.org/security/vulnerabilities_22.html)... That seems... less than ideal. Despite what was [said here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/316632/1081494), that doesn't appear to be maintained. Any plan to update to an _non-EOL_ web server?

Comment: I really have no idea . I'm a humble MSE moderator. I'll ask around, see if I can find someone who knows what's going on and follow up from there. IIRC one of the current CMs owns this so I've pinged him. Its a weekend so... I'd at least want to wait till monday and some change

Comment: Per the answer to my previous question @Laurel linked, the only non-SO sites out of the old ones that were meant to stick around were the Russian Language and Mathematics sites. The former opted to migrate into our network, while the latter opted to remain separate as the rules regarding homework questions would have to change otherwise. The others, including Physics and Tourism (which I didn't know about before), were meant to be shut down along with a bunch of other sites that were indeed shut down, but were kept up due to oversight.

Comment: See [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/284185/377214), the two sections labeled "hashcode.ru acquisition"

Comment: To clarify here: Stack Exchange has absolutely nothing to do with the maintenance of the Hashcode sites. Outside of Nic working here and keeping the servers up, no other SE employee ever touches those sites, has access to do anything with them, or has any say in what happens to them. This is entirely up to Nic and whatever he wants to do with them.

Comment: @animuson who is Nic? And why don't you close this question as off topic? I voted to close, but doubt others will.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's to become of the remaining hashcode.ru sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316022/282094)  - `"Occasionally I do some maintenance on the server but nothing more."` - answered Oct 11, 2018 at 6:50 - Nicolas Chabanovsky [Staff] [Mod]