# Migrated questions over time

Tags: discussion, migration

I was looking at the number of migrated questions on Stack Exchange sites. Here is what I found. I suspect that the peak in 2011 is because of the creation of new Stack Exchange sites and moving questions to those sites.

However, I could not find when each site was created.

1. Where can I find this information?
2. Can anyone point me any hints to this large number of migrated questions at that time?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can find how old each site is by looking at the last column of the [Stack Exchange site list](https://stackexchange.com/sites#oldest):

[image]

You'll see that many new sites were already created in the summer and fall of 2010, before the 2011 peak in migrations.

Alternatively, the first post on each site is the question with ID 1, so if you browse to e.g. [`https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/1`](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/1) you'll see that Ask Different was created (in private beta) on August 17th, 2010. This will fail if the question has been deleted, but @rene's SEDE skills come to the rescue: [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1074991) is a nice overview.

There might be older posts on the site, because of later migrations from even older sites. The oldest question on Ask Different, [Keyboard shortcut for restoring applications from the Mac OS X Dock?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/55432/121968), is from September 2008, but it was originally asked on Stack Overflow.

Area 51 also shows the created date if you hover over the date under 'private beta start' in the sidebar of the [proposal page](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/151/apple):

[image]

> can anyone point me any hints to this large number of migrated questions at that time

I don't have a definitive answer for this, but it might be worthwhile checking [migration](/questions/tagged/migration) questions from around that time: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/migration?tab=newest&page=19&pagesize=50

Comment: Interesting idea to take Postswithdeleted.id=1: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1074991

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! It would be more helpful if I can collect also migrated questions that were rejected. But I can only track those that were rejected shortly after migration. Any thoughts on this.

Comment: That would work with a SEDE query as well (as long as the questions aren't deleted, I guess).

Comment: If you can't find the proposal on Area 51, this is most probably because you are looking for one of these 3 sites: StackOverflow, Server Fault and Super User. (Credits: [Oded's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/284185/468333))