# How can an existing site join the network?

Tags: discussion, area-51, stack-exchange, site-proposal

According to an [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/284185/336163) on [Which Stack Exchange sites weren't proposed in Area 51?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/284184/336163), several of our current network sites were pre-existing sites that somehow "joined" the network and eventually became fully-fledged Stack Exchange 2.0 sites. Most notably, these sites bypassed the entire Area 51 proposal process (definition, commitment, etc.), as they were already-defined sites with already-committed users and substantial pre-existing content to import/migrate.

Today (in 2021), how can an existing *non-Stack Exchange* site join the network? I understand that this happens so rarely that it's unlikely that no two instances have unfolded exactly the same, but what are the broad parameters?

For example, suppose I and a few friends previously set up what has become a highly popular go-to Q&A site on widgets. We have now decided that we're ready to move onto other things and offer to let our site's community migrate its content into a Widgets Stack Exchange and proceed directly to moderator elections and fully-fledged participation in the network. *What would we be expected to do?*

- Do we approach the company directly through the Contact link at the bottom of the page?
- Do we start a placeholder "plz migrate our existing content kthx" proposal on Area 51?
- Do we start a discussion on Meta Stack Exchange?

To be clear, I'm not asking how likely it is that I have or have the potential to develop a site that is worthy enough of acceptance into the network. I admit the likelihood is probably rather low. My question is if I  somehow do build or acquire such a site, what's the process for migrating it to the network?

Comment: I kind of doubt anyone in the company would be at all interested in such a migration unless it was a very active and healthy site with lots of potential. The answer here is very likely: you can't. We don't do it.

Comment: The most recent time that happened was in 2015 when SE bought out hashcode.ru, but in that case, it was *SE who reached out to them*, not the other way around. If you scroll to the second answer there, you'll see several cases where content from previous sites was seeded into current sites, but *only after those current ones were proposed and created through Area 51*.

Comment: You might be able to use Area51 to propose another site with your existing audience, then manually quote the Q&A from the old site, assuming it was created with a permissive enough license.

Answer (score 16):

There is no such process, because it hasn't *technically* been done before.

Several of those sites you mention were actually SE 1.0 sites, built on *our own software*, albeit outdated software. Those were possibly the most straight-forward cases we could possibly encounter as far as migrating them into the network because they already used the same database structures as our own sites did in the past. We intentionally left the door open to those specific sites after the Area 51 process ramped up.

The other case is Hashcode, which did not come to us. We went to them. That was a specific phase where we were interested in opening a Stack Overflow site in Russian, but there was already a thriving community behind that. It made far more sense to integrate that community into the network rather than create a new one. A lot of effort was put into that acquisition as well as migrating the database into our model.

And there lies the true problem. Database migrations are extremely complicated and time-consuming.

To put that into perspective: our Teams product is something that clients actually pay for. Yet even in that instance, it was determined that offering migration or import systems for the product would not be feasible. We allow clients to download a dump of all their data if they cancel and want to keep it all in a downloadable file. Even in that case we offer no utility for re-uploading that data if they decide to come back to Teams later.

It is also worth mentioning that our willingness to engage in many activities has dwindled over the years. We previously offered the ability to seed new Area 51 sites with content from previously failed sites or smaller sub-sites that were willing to essentially start over somewhere new. We no longer offer this "seeding" option.

So in all likelihood, any method you opted for to try and contact us for integrating such a site would likely be rejected without much of a second thought. We're simply not interested in such a prospect.