# Site recommendation questions and offsite alternatives - could we set some boundaries for sites outside the network?

Tags: discussion, flags

I've recently come across a few answers where folks recommended a site on another Q&A network and it attracted spam flags and downvotes.

I'm personally fine with other Q&A sites and networks in context - say, [here where folks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/are-there-any-clones-alternatives-for-running-a-stack-exchange-style-qa-site) are talking about alternatives, and here where OP talks of [moving off teams to qpixel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/330033/135565). That said - for all intents and purposes, meta.stackexchange is meant to serve and be about the stack exchange network, and answers to site recommendation questions ought to be about sites *here*. The tag wiki, while mutable reflects this.

While there's a few clear cut cases where external site recommendations are *spam* - the communities that spun off kind of are in a place where we can actually communicate the ground rules for interactions between our community, and I'd rather not treat them as I would a garden variety spammer.

Internally - I wonder if custom "no foul" flags would be better than spam flags in some cases as such.

I would like to set mutually respectful boundaries here so - might there be anything I'd have missed or any specific points of interest that might be worth bringing up?

Comment: Not sure what you wish to discuss: the act of flagging, or only the type of flag being used? I mean, do you think that some answers linking to external sites in site-rec questions are valid and should stay, or do you mean they should go away, but not spam?

Comment: Yes. :D .  Fundamentally - I'd like a more formal place to point at than 'just' the tag wiki excerpt for pointing folks who link to other sites in good faith and how we deal with such posts is an integral part of the issue to me.

Comment: So what would we do with a borderline case like this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/47158/361484

Comment: Well based on mod actions, I'd say it's pointless to discuss it, decision already been made: any answer suggesting external site is going to be deleted.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard Deleting as off-topic is one thing, deleting *as spam* is another.

Comment: How about this: if you offer outbound suggestions, at least offer two distinct options? So reddit and Quora is Okay but only 4chan isn't?

Comment: I know someone who *might* know of decent technical information on 4 chan.... :D

Comment: @rene that would give double spam penalty, -200 rep.

Answer (score 13):

When no on-topic site exists in the Stack Exchange network, a good-faith pointer to a site outside the Stack Exchange network is not spam, in particular not when this post is not described as an advertisement but points out the downsides as well.

For example, recently, I [posted an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/382441/172266) related to a request for a site where nothing relevant exists within the Stack Exchange network.  My answer posted to a site where I am not personally active, and from my answer it was clear the linked community might not be a great solution either, due to the very small number of relevant posts.   I admit that I did not read the tag wiki description before posting an answer (who does?), and I can see how Meta Stack Exchange is not "Q&A resource recommendations", but I quite strongly reject allegations that my answer could be considered spam.

Answer (score 8):

Speaking on behalf of the project that sparked this discussion, https://codidact.org, we do not endorse anybody spamming or otherwise inappropriately posting links to our project and communities. The staff of the Codidact Foundation are committed to following all guidelines that have been set out in regards to promotion on the Stack Exchange network. While we cannot of course control the actions of our users, we discourage anybody from promoting us or our projects in a way counter to the guidelines for posting on Stack Exchange (e.g. link-only answers). We want to maintain a positive relationship with SE as much as possible, and spamming benefits nobody in this case. (I'd note that several Codidact folks are or were active in [Charcoal](https://charcoal-se.org/), which is dedicated to *removing* spam from SE; we're not going to turn around and start undermining that.) We're also willing to give folks a slap on the wrist from our end when necessary.

With that said, as gerrit stated in their answer. I believe that it is not unreasonable to suggest an alternative site, including one of Codidact's communities, when there is no SE site that meets what the question is asking for. When no Stack Exchange site is suitable for a particular question, the answer "Stack Exchange does not support this type of question, see Reddit instead" should be acceptable, with whatever alternative the answerer feels like providing.

When it comes to spam flags, I think that generally those shouldn't be necessary. As I stated above, all official staff members of this project are committed to not spamming, which means that in this particular case, the level of affiliation required to qualify for spam is questionable. Obviously, this should be judged on a case-by-case basis; there could very well be cases where spam flags are necessary, and I generally trust the SE mods enough to make those judgement calls. For the most part, though, I'd err on avoiding spam flags - being too hasty with them can lead to answers being [spam-masked and deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382443/site-recommendation-questions-and-offsite-alternatives-could-we-set-some-bound/382446#comment1275592_382446) when the answerer isn't even involved with the site they're suggesting.

I'd like to also note that we take this matter seriously, and are in the process of reaching out to the users involved in the case alluded to in Tinkeringbell's answer. We're taking steps to make sure that they know that we highly discourage inappropriate promotion. We also fully support SE mods taking the necessary steps such as warnings and suspensions when they feel it necessary; we're not asking for special treatment. We'd just like to not get special treatment in terms of "delete on sight" either ;)

Answer (score -1):

> Site recommendation questions and offsite alternatives - could we set some boundaries for sites outside the network?

The boundary has already been set, though perhaps it isn't easy to find as it's been in the guidance tied to the [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) tag since 2019. The boundary is pretty clear, that site recommendation questions are for questions about where to post on the SE network, and not outside of it.

So recommending anything but an SE network site is a no-go.

> the communities that spun off kind of are in a place where we can actually communicate the ground rules for interactions between our community, and I'd rather not treat them as I would a garden variety spammer.

I've observed those communications being had several times before. Yet, new posts keep cropping up, so it's safe to say we're probably past the part  where we should be thinking that communicating helps fix the problem of these posts being made.

And while garden variety spammers get their accounts destroyed (with or without a long suspension first), with these posts so far we've just been deleting them without invalidating the spam flags first. The spam flags stay because in a sense those posts *are* spam. Those posts you're talking about are, as far as I have observed (with so far one exception pointed out in the comments that I did not observe) made by users (sometimes seemingly even staff) to drive traffic to another site, without disclosing their affiliation with that site.

I think the community here should be free to keep flagging those posts as spam, there's no need to start expecting them to do anything else.

If these posts keep showing up, I think it's us moderators that need to be changing our approach: The communications you mention are failing as these posts keep showing up, so we should start deleting them as spam, instead of just deleting them without invalidating/declining the spam flags first.

Comment: _Those posts you're talking about are made by users (sometimes seemingly even staff) to drive traffic to another site, without disclosing their affiliation with that site._, at least for [my recently deleted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/382441/172266), this is **not** the case.  I pointed to a site where I am not an active user.

Comment: @gerrit and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/357685/369802) is one that *is*. Fine, so there's one recent exception to the pattern I have observed, answer updated.

Comment: Could you please provide some examples of affiliated users making these posts? As an affiliated user, I'd like to know what you're referring to so that I can ask people to stop if necessary. (I saw the one linked in the comment above.)

Comment: @Tinkeringbell I can't see deleted posts except my own, so I'll take your word that it's usually spam.

Comment: @Mithical Meh. The only easy way for me to easily track back some more is by looking at which ones were talked about in e.g. chat. Those would fall under "I've observed those communications being had several times before.", and you (or other affiliated users) will already know about those, as you are often the person contacted anyways. If you don't mind, not going to waste time on that.

Comment: I can recall one case in recent history, so I'm wondering if there are more that I'm not aware of.

Comment: The way that I read that tag wiki that you refer to is barring _questions_ expressly looking for off-site resources, not answers from recommending things in a good-natured, non-spam way. It seems silly to not recommend the best place for a topic unilaterally, particularly if the question doesn't fit on Stack Exchange at all.