# What unlisted, but public, Stack Exchange sites exist in the Stack Exchange network?

Tags: support, stack-exchange

I recently found out about [CS50 Stack Exchange](https://cs50.stackexchange.com), which appears to be a normal beta Stack Exchange site (I was able to sign up immediately and receive the standard Association Bonus, etc.), but I noticed that it neither appears on the [All Sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#) list nor the Communities list that appears when you click the SE hamburger menu logo.

At first, I assumed that CS50 was probably a private beta, but there is no corresponding proposal on Area 51 for anything called CS50. The site also seems to have questions dating back to at least 2014, which is a very long time indeed for a site to stay in private beta.

What *publicly accessible* Stack Exchange sites currently exist in the Stack Exchange network, but *do not appear* in the standard listings? That is, these are sites that anyone can, in theory, sign up for, but which are not normally disclosed to users via the standard methods for informing users about available sites. This could be because they are highly niche, controversial, or have been explicitly removed from the listings for some other reason.

Comment: [Details for CS50](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228721/what-is-cs50-and-why-cant-i-access-it). It's a unique site in the sense it's not private beta, but is hidden from the site lists as if it was. Since it's the only one and unlikely more will follow, guess we shouldn't do anything about it.

Comment: *"cs50 - For students of HarvardX [CS50x: Introduction to Computer Science](https://online-learning.harvard.edu/course/cs50-introduction-computer-science/)"*

Comment: @Peter exactly. My question was whether that is the only one - e.g. whether there is a "CD10.SE - For students of Podunk Open Community Pool's *CD10 - Introduction to Intermediate Concepts in Advanced Competitive Diving*". People who don't live anywhere near Podunk probably wouldn't care to learn that the site exists, but people who *do*, might.